# Filtering properties and placeholders in spring

Tags: java, spring, properties, configuration, placeholder

How can I avoid repetition with spring placeholders? Usually I load all the properties and later use them one by one, repeating everything 3 times (properties file, property name from xml, placeholder name):

```
<context:property-placeholder location="classpath:/spring/application.properties,
                                        classpath:/spring/${env}.properties" />

<bean id="dataSource" class="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource" destroy-method="close">
        <property name="properties">
            <value>
                user = ${db.user}
                password = ${db.passwd}
            </value>
        </property>
</bean>
```

I can do:

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource" destroy-method="close">
        <property name="properties" ref="allProperties"/>
</bean>
```

However, it's not a good solution because:

- If I have many components then there can be some properties clash
- I don't want passing passwords
- I also don't want to split my configuration files per each component. I want to have 1 global file and 1 file per each environment. Splitting properties would make it hard to maintain

So the question is:
Is there anything that would let me choose properties (by prefix) that should be passed? Something like:

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource" destroy-method="close">
        <property name="properties">
            <bean class="...PropertiesFilter">
                <property name="prefix" value="c3p0"/>
                <property name="src" ref="allProperties"/>
            </bean>
        </property>
</bean>
```

I know, it's not hard to write but maybe spring already has something like that (with better syntax).

Comment: if the ComboPooledDataSource is something you can change, just use the @Value annotation to inject the properties.